# refreshing Value Converter on INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, ivalueconverter

I know there are some similar topics here but I couldn't get any answer from them.
I have to update background of a grid to either an image or a colour in my Windows Phone 7 app. I do this using my value converter , it works fine but I'd have to reload the collection so it updates the colour or image.

```
<Grid Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" Width="125" Height="125" Margin="6">
```

The converter receives the object then gets the color and image from it, here is the converter

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {

            People myC = value as People;

            string myImage = myC.Image;
            object result = myC.TileColor;

            if (myImage != null)
            {

                BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
                bi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.BackgroundCreation;
                ImageBrush imageBrush = new ImageBrush();

                using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(myImage))
                    {

                        using (
                            IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(myImage, FileMode.Open,
                                                                                              FileAccess.Read))
                        {
                            bi.SetSource(fileStream);
                            imageBrush.ImageSource = bi;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return result;
                    }
                }

                return imageBrush;
            }
            else
            {
                return result;
            }

    }
```

I need to somehow update/refresh the grid tag or the value converter so that it can show the latest changes !

**EDIT**

**ADDED SOME MORE CODE**

The model :

```
  [Table]
    public class People : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
    {


        private int _peopleId;

        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "INT NOT NULL Identity", CanBeNull = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
        public int PeopleId
        {
            get { return _peopleId; }
            set
            {
                if (_peopleId != value)
                {
                    NotifyPropertyChanging("PeopleId");
                    _peopleId = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("PeopleId");
                }
            }
        }

        private string _peopleName;

        [Column]
        public string PeopleName
        {
            get { return _peopleName; }
            set
            {
                if (_peopleName != value)
                {
                    NotifyPropertyChanging("PeopleName");
                    _peopleName = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("PeopleName");
                }
            }
        }




        private string _tileColor;

        [Column]
        public string TileColor
        {
            get { return _tileColor; }
            set
            {
                if (_tileColor != value)
                {
                    NotifyPropertyChanging("TileColor");
                    _tileColor = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("TileColor");
                }
            }
        }



        private string _image;

        [Column]
        public string Image
        {
            get { return _image; }
            set
            {
                if (_image != value)
                {
                    NotifyPropertyChanging("Image");
                    _image = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Image");
                }
            }
        }


        [Column]
        internal int _groupId;

        private EntityRef<Groups> _group;

        [Association(Storage = "_group", ThisKey = "_groupId", OtherKey = "Id", IsForeignKey = true)]
        public Groups Group
        {
            get { return _group.Entity; }
            set
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("Group");
                _group.Entity = value;

                if (value != null)
                {
                    _groupId = value.Id;
                }

                NotifyPropertyChanging("Group");
            }
        }


        [Column(IsVersion = true)]
        private Binary _version;

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region INotifyPropertyChanging Members

        public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanging(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanging != null)
            {
                PropertyChanging(this, new PropertyChangingEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

ViewModel :

```
public class PeopleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private PeopleDataContext PeopleDB;

    // Class constructor, create the data context object.
    public PeopleViewModel(string PeopleDBConnectionString)
    {
        PeopleDB = new PeopleDataContext(PeopleDBConnectionString);
    }


    private ObservableCollection<People> _allPeople;

    public ObservableCollection<People> AllPeople
    {
        get { return _allPeople; }
        set
        {
            _allPeople = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("AllPeople");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<People> LoadPeople(int gid)
    {
        var PeopleInDB = from People in PeopleDB.People
                           where People._groupId == gid
                           select People;


        AllPeople = new ObservableCollection<People>(PeopleInDB);

        return AllPeople;
    }


    public void updatePeople(int cid, string cname, string image, string tilecol)
    {
        People getc = PeopleDB.People.Single(c => c.PeopleId == cid);
        getc.PeopleName = cname;
        getc.Image = image;
        getc.TileColor = tilecol;

        PeopleDB.SubmitChanges();

    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Application Page

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

        <ListBox Margin="0,8,0,0"  x:Name="Peoplelist" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  BorderThickness="4" ItemsSource="{Binding AllPeople}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" Width="125" Height="125" Margin="6">
                        <TextBlock Name="name" Text="{Binding PeopleName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ListBox>

    </Grid>
```

Application Page code behind

```
public partial class PeopleList : PhoneApplicationPage
{

    private int gid;
    private bool firstRun;

    public PeopleList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        firstRun = true;
        this.DataContext = App.ViewModel;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        gid = int.Parse(NavigationContext.QueryString["Id"]);

        if (firstRun)
        {
            App.ViewModel.LoadPeople(gid);
            firstRun = false;
        }


    }

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}"` suggests you bind directly to `People` **item** (which is your problem when refreshing).

So, you should rearrange a bit. Make that `a property` of some other 'higher' data context instead.

---

**How to rearrange things:**

1) **your 'model' (entity from db) should be different than your view-model**. To avoid going into details, it solves lot of problems - e.g. like you're having. The `People` getters/setters are not normally overriden in that way (EF often uses reflection to deal w/ entities etc.).
So, make PeopleVM (for single People or `PersonViewModel`) - copy things in there - and make INotify in there - leave People just a pure entity/poco w/ automatic get/set.

2) Same for the `PeopleViewModel` - it's too tied-up to the Db (these are also design guidelines).
**You shouldn't reuse the DbContext** - don't save it - it's a 'one off' object (and cached inside) - so use `using()` to deal with and load/update on demand.

3) **Replace People in your main VM with PersonViewModel**. When you load from db, pump up into the PersonVM first - when you're saving the other way around. That's a tricky bit with MVVM, you often need to copy/duplicate - you could use some tool for that to automate or just make copy ctor-s or something.
Your `ObservableCollection<People> AllPeople` becomes `ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel> AllPeople`

4) XAML - your binding AllPeople, PeopleName is the same - but that points now to view-models (and Name to VM Name).
But **you should bind your `grid` to something other than `PersonViewModel` (old People)** - as that is hard to 'refresh' when inside the collection.
a) Make a new single property like `ImageAndTileColor` - and make sure it updates/notifies on / when any of the two properties change.
b) The other option is to use `MultiBinding` - and bind 2, 3 properties - one being the whole `PersonViewModel` like you have and plus those other two properties - e.g...

```
<Grid ...>
    <Grid.Background>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ImageConverter}" Mode="OneWay">
            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                <Binding Path="Image" />
                <Binding Path="TileColor" />
                <Binding Path="" />
            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Grid.Background>
    <TextBlock Name="name" Text="{Binding PeopleName}" ... />
</Grid>
```

**That way you force the binding to refresh when any of the 3 changes** - and you still have your full People in there (actually you could just use two as all you need is Image and TileColor).

5) Change your Converter to be IMultiValue... and to read multiple values sent in.

That's all :)

**SHORT VERSION:**
That was the `proper way` and certain to work (it depends on how/when you update Person properties etc.) - but you could try the `short version` first - just do the `multi-binding` part on the People model - and hope it'd work. If it doesn't you have to do all the above.

**Windows Phone 7:**
Since there is no `MultiBinding`...
  - Use [the workaround](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/MultiBinding_for_Silverlight_3.aspx) - it should be quite similar,
  - Or go with the `(a)` above - bind grid to `{Binding ImageAndTileColor, Converter...}`. Make new property (you can do the same if you wish in the entity/model - just mark it as `[NotMapped()]`) which would be a 'composite' one.

---

http://www.thejoyofcode.com/MultiBinding_for_Silverlight_3.aspx

Comment: A collection which I set it to my listbox itemsource in the code behind list.ItemsSource = App.ViewModel.AllPeople;  all work fine but the grid background doesn't change (The other things like texts and things that aren't using value converter gets updated immediately )

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can I ask what exactly you mean by refreshing my collection ? I'm loading my data to an observable collection in my page constructor, but after that I just call the already loaded collection from the cache.

Comment: I can edit it and it will work without needing to reload the data from the database (INotify works fine so far) but if I change any picture which means it needs the value converter to check if the picture or background has been changed, then it doesn't show the updated background unless I reload the collection from the database . Now I wanna know if I am supposed to load the collection from the database each time I update it or this void the purpose of INotifypropertychanged !?

Comment: Sure, I'll post them soon . Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot, but does Windows Phone 7 supports multi binding ? I couldn't implement IMultiValueConverter !

Comment: Then go with the option `a` - I gave you that too :) (I admit I overlooked that part, but it's similar code in most and the main ideas definitely apply)

Comment: How can I bind my grid to something else coz the listbox (which is its parent) is bound to PersonViewModel , besides the Image and TileColor are read and set based on the current person's ID

Comment: Right, but I mean how can I link ImageAndTileColor with the current user data as I would have to populate ImageAndTileColor with something , right ? which would be ? I need either an object to go to the converter so that I can get Image and TileColor out of it or the Person's ID so that I can read its Image and TileColor from the database from inside the converter ! sorry I'm a bit confused .

Comment: let it 'sink' :) I have work to do, I'm just giving you guidelines which are correct you gotta work the rest. I'd say multi-converter work-around if that's easier (it's cleaner), and don't ask me about that, I don't know, just seems what you need. For ImageAndTile - make temp object - that's only in 'view-model' - or a Tupple you can use - and the important bit is just to call Notify("ImageAndTile") when either of the two changes - hope that helps :)

Comment: Cool, I'll try using MultiBinding and let you know about the result .

Comment: Here is one more idea - in your PersonVM you can just expose PersonVM (self - i.e. `this`) - and bind to that property - no object needed - you just need to do OnPropertyChanged("MySelf") when either of the properties change. That's if you go w/ 'no multi-binding'. With multi... you don't need any of that just the binding and converter.

Answer (score 0):

I got it (Thanks to NSGaga). I set his post as the answer, the following is what I did

First I needed to make the converter to receive PeopleId instead of the object itself

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {

        int cid = (int)value;
        People myC = App.ViewModel.getPerson(cid);

            string myImage = myC.Image;
            object result = myC.TileColor;

            if (myImage != null)
            {

                BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
                bi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.BackgroundCreation;
                ImageBrush imageBrush = new ImageBrush();

                using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(myImage))
                    {

                        using (
                            IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(myImage, FileMode.Open,
                                                                                              FileAccess.Read))
                        {
                            bi.SetSource(fileStream);
                            imageBrush.ImageSource = bi;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return result;
                    }
                }

                return imageBrush;
            }
            else
            {
                return result;
            }

    }
```

Then I just had to add call `NotifyPropertyChanged("PeopleId")` whenever I update Image or TileColor like this

```
    private string _tileColor;

    [Column]
    public string TileColor
    {
        get { return _tileColor; }
        set
        {
            if (_tileColor != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("TileColor");
                _tileColor = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("TileColor");
                NotifyPropertyChanged("PeopleId");
            }
        }
    }



    private string _image;

    [Column]
    public string Image
    {
        get { return _image; }
        set
        {
            if (_image != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("Image");
                _image = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Image");
                NotifyPropertyChanged("PeopleId");
            }
        }
    }
```

This forces the value converter to refresh :)