# INotifyPropertyChanged when binding to object itself instead of a property

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm doing some binding in Windows Phone 8's WPF form. I've got a list bound to the object itself:

```
{Binding .}
```

That object implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. In a scenario where I bind to a property on that object:

```
{Binding someProperty}
```

I can call the property changed event and my list will be updated. However, in the case that I'm bound to my object itself, how can I notify the list that the object changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A short answer is...

1) If you want for it to update - and INotify... to work - you either need to reorganize your view-models a bit - and bind to a property - of a 'parent view model'.

2) Or you could make up one 'temp property' - e.g.
`public YourObject MySelf {get{return this;}set{}}`

3) Or in some cases (depends on what you have) you could use `MultiBinding` with `{Binding .}` (this) and some other property - which is then 'notified' (the other property).

I've described this in some more details here (**point #4**)
[refreshing Value Converter on INotifyPropertyChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868582/refreshing-value-converter-on-inotifypropertychanged/15868643#15868643)